# Error: Type '[number] | [number, number, number, number]' is not assignable to type '[number]'

Tags: angular, typescript

After the update from the angular 5.1 to 6.1 I stared to receive some error from my code like the following:

> Error: ngc compilation failed: components/forms/utils.ts(5,3): error
>   TS2322: Type '[number] | [number, number, number, number]' is not
>   assignable to type '[number]'.

Follows the code:

```
export function bsColumnClass(sizes: [number]) {

  let sizebs = ['col-xs-', 'col-sm-', 'col-md-', 'col-lg-',];

  sizes = sizes || [12, 12, 12, 12];

  let className = sizes.map(function callback(value, index, array) {
    return sizebs[index].concat(value.toString());
  }).join(" ");

  return className;
}
```

I notice that the problem is because I have a function parameter `sizes: [number]` and after that I'm traing to do this line of code: `sizes = sizes || [12, 12, 12, 12];`

Can you tell me the better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define an array of numbers the syntax is `number[]` (and in general for arrays we have `type[]`). What you defined there is a tuple type, which has a fixed number of elements and can have heterogeneous element types.

```
export function bsColumnClass(sizes: number[]) {


}
```

Or if you want to mandate the caller pass exactly 4 elements in the array, which appears to make sense in this case as `sizebs` is fixed,  you can use the tuple type:

```
export function bsColumnClass(sizes: [number, number, number, number]) {

  let sizebs = ['col-xs-', 'col-sm-', 'col-md-', 'col-lg-',];

  sizes = sizes || [12, 12, 12, 12];

  let className = sizes.map(function callback(value, index, array) {
    return sizebs[index].concat(value.toString());
  }).join(" ");

  return className;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Typescript, arrays are declared in the following way

```
type[]
```

instead of

```
[type]
```

if you try to write your code with theses changes, it should work, however, correct me if I'm wrong, but, are you trying to assign a list of number to sizes in case sizes is undefined ?

If so, you should type your function accordingly

```
function bsColumnClass(sizes?: number[]) {
}
```

The **?** will ensure that event if you don't provide a variable to the function, the code stays statically typed and accept a variable argument

Answer (score 0):

In question I found syntax problem in argument `sizes: [number]` instead of that you can use `sizes: number[]`.

You can try this:

```
export function bsColumnClass(sizes: number[]) {
  const sizebs = ['col-xs-', 'col-sm-', 'col-md-', 'col-lg-'];

  sizes = sizes || [12, 12, 12, 12];

  const className = sizes
    .map(function callback(value, index, array) {
      return sizebs[index].concat(value.toString());
    })
    .join(' ');

  return className;
}

//bsColumnClass([1, 2, 6, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues just recently in an Ngx-chart library. My Angular version is `14.2.6`

What fixed it for me was storing the properties in separate variables. For example instead of

```js
sizes = sizes || [12, 12, 12, 12];
```

Do this

```js
w: number = 12;
x: number = 12;
y: number = 12;
z: number = 12;
```

and then you can use these variables directly on markup.

```js
[attrName]="[w, x, y, z]"
```